# Fourier transform, notation of wave number and space?

Tags: fourier-transform

I have been confused by a notation (?) of Fourier transformation.
When I was reading a paper, I saw a definition of Fourier transform and its inverse as

$(\mathcal{F}f)(k)=\int_{D}f(x)e^{-2i\pi<x,k>} {\rm{d}}x,\quad 
(\mathcal{F}f)(x)=\int_{D}f(k)e^{2i\pi<x,k>} {\rm{d}}k$.

I have two questions with these equations.

1. Isn't $k$ frequency, like $\omega$? Fourier transform maps a function in spatial domain to frequency domain, right? However, it seems that $k$ here is a integer.
2. What is $<x,k>$? Is this just a multiplication? What is implied by putting them in <>?

I might be asking silly questions due to my background, but it would be super helpful if you could give me some hints to solve my questions.
Thank you so much.

Comment: In physics, $k$ is the wavevector and has units of reciprocal length. (By contrast, $x$ has units of length and thus the product will be dimensionless.) This is analogous to frequency but not equivalent: $k$ describes spatial variation whereas $\omega$ describes temporal variation. As for $\langle x,k\rangle$, it’s presumably the inner product between $x$ and $k$ as vectors; this isn’t terribly common notation in physics, but it may be more common in other disciplines.

Comment: Thank you so much. Then, when $k$ and $x$ are vectors, the integral is not a scalar but a vector, as well? 
@Gonçalo: Fixed. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Is $k$ here a integer? No, right?

Comment: Thank you. The reason I asked you this is because in a paper I am reading, they say something like "since the function is periodic and thus it accepts Fourier series expansion. Therefore, we can work with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$". Would you tell me why $k=2\pi/\lambda$ can be an integer?

Comment: A more specific reference would be needed to clarify the paper's intention, but taken at face value you're correct: a wavenumber cannot be an integer. (One exception is if you're working with a particle on a ring: in that case, the 'coordinate' is the angle of the particle along the ring. Then the units of 'length' are dimensionless and so too will be the wavenumber. In that context, it's a bit confusing but not altogether wrong to talk about integer values of $k$.)